# how to move each cell below each other

Tags: r, matrix

I have a large matrix with 322560 elements and 8 columns, like this:

```
 [1,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8
 [2,]    1    4    3    2    5    6    8    7
 [3,]    2    1    5    4    3    8    6    7
 [4,]    5    8    4    3    2    1    6    7
 .....
```

I need to create a matrix only with one column, but keeping the order of the cells as they appear in each row. This is what I would like to obtain:

```
 1 #from 1st row
 2   
 3    
 4    
 5    
 6    
 7    
 8  
 1 #from 2nd row    
 4    
 3    
 2    
 5    
 6    
 8    
 7  
 2 #from 3rd row   
 1    
 5    
 4    
 3    
 8    
 6    
 7 
 5 #from 4th row    
 8    
 4    
 3    
 2    
 1    
 6    
 7
 .....
```

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: or for 1-column `matrix(t(m))`

Comment: @user20650 shouldn't that be an answer? :)